# Seeking paypal parallel payment tutorial/sample Android

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I need to implement Paypal parallel payment in my android application. Paypal-android-sdk doesn't support parallel payments. Paypal has adaptivePaymentSDKs for ruby, java etc but don't have for android.

It would be great if someone mention any link about "Parallel payments in Android".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to page 19 of the Android Developer Guide Parallel payments are available to the Android application.

[Page 19 Parallel Payments Android Developer Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf)

Here are three other helpful links. Based on all the documentation Java is used for Android:

[SDK for Adaptive Payments Java](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#adaptive-payments)

[Parallel Payment Setup](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc)

[Adaptive Payments Basics](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_dev_Datasheet_APP_R3.pdf)

[PayPal Cardova Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-cordova-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know parallel payments are available to android :) My question is "What is the best way to implement them"? paypal-android-sdk doesn't support parallel payments then h"ow should we implement them?"

Comment: Just updated my answer with more resources including an sdk for adaptive payments in Java.

Comment: @AhmadRaza did you get any solution for implementing parallel payments?

Comment: @AhmadRaza The replacement for Adaptive payments is now available for select partners and it is PayPal for Marketplaces: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/